# Updating ruby script to append keys with different values once condition is met

Tags: ruby, csv

I have the following script that filters for rows with a certain property type:

```
require "csv"

input = "property-assessment-fy2017.csv"
output = "filtered_bos.csv"

def filter(row)
  row["PTYPE"] == "13"
end

#run
CSV.open(output, "wb") do |csv|
  i = 0
  CSV.foreach(input, :headers => true) do |row|
    csv << row.headers  if i == 0 # header row
    if filter(row)
      csv << row.fields
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

I'd like to add some code that will identify rows with duplicate values for the column "PID" and then append all the values into one row.

For example:

Before:

```
#PID | ST Number | Street | Year
# 1  |    123    |  Test  | 2015
# 2  |    345    |  Fake  | 2007
# 2  |    345    |  Fake  | 2010
```

After:

```
#PID | ST Number | Street | Year
# 1  |    123    |  Test  | 2015
# 2  |    345    |  Fake  | 2007; 2010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a key for the columns you expect to be unique, like this, row.fields[0], and store the row index into the hash for the item you push to csv array. if a row matches already pushed row, then pull the prev row by using csv[hsh[key]] and edit the 'year' column, like this 'csv[hsh[key]][3] += row.fields[-1]'

```
hsh = {}  
CSV.open(output, "wb") do |csv|
 i = 0
 CSV.foreach(input, :headers => true) do |row|
   if i == 0 # header row
      csv << row.headers 
      i += 1 
   else
      if filter(row)
        key = row.fields[0]
        if hsh[key]
          csv[hsh[key]][3] = csv[hsh[key]][3].to_s + '; ' + row.fields[-1].to_s
        else
          hsh[key] = i
          csv << row.fields 
          i += 1
        end
      end
   end
 end
end
```